# Control white spaces after figures in float package

Tags: floats

I've been using this code in my preamble to control the float of all my figures and tables in my document. However, I think it adds an unnecassary white space before and after each figure/table. Is there any way to control this and minimise the space between figures/a figure and text?

```
\usepackage{float}
\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][2] {
    \expandafter\origfigure\expandafter[H]
} {
    \endorigfigure
}
```

Comment: latex floats figures to avoid getting bad white space at page breaks. `[H]` disables floating so _by design_ introduces bad white space that you choose to manually fix by moving the figure by hand in the source so that it appears in a good place with respect to page breaking. You are also adding additional white space tokens due to missing `%` at ends of lines in the definition, but  using `[H]` would be the main issue.

Comment: `\renewenvironment{figure}[1][2]` makes the default value of the optional argument  be `[2]` which would be an error except that you never use the optional argument at all.

Comment: `\expandafter\origfigure\expandafter[H` expands `H` which is not expandable, you can delete both `\expandafter` as they are doing nothing.

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle, is there perhaps a better way to keep figures/tables in the position they are in my document and avoid the big white spaces without using a float? All of my figures and tables go to the end of my document without using a float so I'm trying to fix that

Comment: The _only_ purpose of the `figure` environment is to specify that the content may be moved. `[H]` makes sense as an occasional one-off over-ride but it doesn't make sense to make all figures do that, you may as well not use figure at all. I guess this question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text

Comment: Note that [ht] usually does the same thing as [H], and only moves the figure when [H] would leave a big hole in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][2] {
    \expandafter\origfigure\expandafter[H]
} {
    \endorigfigure
}
```

and ask about white space. Almost every line could potentially add white space.

`\renewenvironment{figure}[1][2]`

this defines `\begin{figure}` to be an environment with one optional argument, if the option is not used then `\begin{figure}` is equivalent to `\begin{figure}[2]` (this was presumably not intended as `2` has no defined behaviour here) As the optional argument is not used at all, the default is arbitrary, perhaps `[1][]` would be clearer.

`{`

This adds a space token at the start of the definition, this could, depending where the `figure` is placed may produce a spurious additional line of white space in the resulting document. It is usually better to use `{%` so no space token is added to the definition.

`\expandafter\origfigure\expandafter[H]`

This expands the non expandable token `H` before calling `\origfigure` so this is equivalent to

`\origfigure[H]`

As above this adds a space token to the start of the environment, this is less likely to generate white space in the output, but again ending the line with `%` is good practice.

As `#1` is not used the user-supplied or default positioning argument is ignored here and `[H]` is always used.

`H` by design produces bad white space at page breaks, as the reason for floating figures is to avoid bad page breaks and this disables that. A better alternative would be just to use `\includegraphics` directly as `figure` is only there to specify that the figure is a float (ie, may be moved). `H` (which was actually my idea originally:-) is just for final manual over-ride and manual positioning in final edit stages of a document, it should never be used as a default mechanism.

`} {`

Again the end of line here adds a space token and as in the first line this will produce white space in the output in some cases.